# PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise(4.2.0) in rails(4.2.6).

In my application, I use nested attributes in user and profile table. I need to validate the password only if I create the new record, the password field is not validated when I update the created records.

My **user.rb** file is:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile
 has_one :company_profile
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
 attr_accessor :profile_updation


 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 validates_presence_of :email, if: :email_required?


 validates_presence_of :password, if: :password_required?
 validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?

 protected

 def email_required?
   true && profile_updation.blank?
 end

 def password_required?
   !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?

 end

end
```

When I run my application this error occurred:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email" DETAIL: Key (email)=() already exists. : INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name", "last_name", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

I searched this issue but I am not able to solve it.

User & profile table in **schemafile**

```ruby
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
   t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
   t.string   "reset_password_token"
   t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
   t.datetime "remember_created_at"
   t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
   t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
   t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
   t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
   t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
   t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
   t.string   "first_name"
   t.string   "last_name"
   t.string   "user_id"
 end

 add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
 add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree        
 add_index "profiles", ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "company_name"
   t.integer  "country"
   t.integer  "state"
   t.integer  "business"
   t.string   "mobile_no"
   t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
   t.integer  "user_id"
   t.boolean  "terms_conditions"
 end
```

Comment: add your schema file to the question (located in `db/schema.rb`)

Comment: Are you trying to sign up using an existing email?

Comment: no i am update the existing user details(first name,last name,etc)

Comment: "When i run my application this error is occurred."-- you need to tell us what code is running when you run your application. None of the code you posted is, alone, enough to cause that error. Most likely, your application code is just trying to insert two users with the same email address.

Comment: Max i need to override the devise validation in user table,the user table has nested attribute(profile).I need to validate the password field if i create a new user profile, at the same time password field is not validate if i edit the user profile...i hope it will helps to understand my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67964990/3437900

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I too had faced the same problem,
drop the database and recreate it.

```html
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 48):

Take a look at your `test/fixtures/users.yml` file and comment out any blank fixtures. See example below:

```
#one: {}
#two: {}
```

Comment: @xenetics Because that is commenting out the definition of two blank models, `one` and `two`. If the models have no property set in the fixture, then it defaults to null. If you have a validation against null or duplicate rows, then it will fail when inserting two nulls for the same column.

Comment: This should be upvoted. Some generators couldn't provide good fixtures based on validations.
So far `devise` is an example.

Comment: Thanks for your mention, I now know the issue is happend here, because I didn't create the whole set test data in fixtures/xxxx.yml.

Comment: This worked well. Highly undervalued answer

Answer (score 4):

You are inserting a user without an email and you already have one.  If you want to ignore blanks on the duplicate check, change your validator:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :uniqueness => {:allow_blank => true}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

After you perform all of Devise's setup steps, two things are true:

1. There are two users defined in the fixtures for the User model tests, `one` and `two`. Those users are empty. They don't have values for any attributes.
2. There is a uniqueness constraint in your `db/schema.rb` file for the `email` column of the `users` table. This will cause your database to raise an error if a user with an email already contained in an existing user is to be persisted.

This means if you don't make the fixture records different by choosing a different emails for each, or delete one of them, you will get a uniqueness constraint error.

Answer (score 1):

in some situation you import your Postgres DB and maybe it's not a good solution to drop a database and you need your data so you can alter seq field with the below psql command:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE $sequence_name RESTART WITH $ID;
* ID is a start value of $sequence_name
```

Answer (score 0):

My unique special snowflake problem was I had polymorphic models and there were multiple fixtures with different model names but which inherit from the same table.

```
class Student < User
class ContentCreator < User
class Admin < User
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def admin
    self.type == "Admin"
  end
  def student
    self.type == "Student"
  end
  ...
```

So even though I had only one entry in `user.yml`, there were multiple entries in the other files like `students.yml`

```
one: {}
# column: value    
two: {}
#  column: value
```

That is probably a bug in the rails generators, or else it wasn't cleaned up after those models were sub-classed.

Answer (score 0):

This is succeeded with me

```
$ CREATE SEQUENCE roles_id_seq;
$ ALTER TABLE roles ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('roles_id_seq'::regclass);
$ ALTER SEQUENCE roles_id_seq OWNED BY roles.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used devised in generating my users and I got this error when I run my test.
I just added the following in my `tests/fixtures/users.yml` file.

```
admin:
  id: 1
  email: admin@testmail.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>

staff:
  id: 2
  email: staff@testmail.com
  encrypted_password: <%= Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'password') %>
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

Now, my tests are working fine.