# Ruby on Rails Testing - ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "xxx_xxxx_xxxx_pkey"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, testing

**I have the following Models. I am using Rails 6.0.3.2 (Ruby 2.7.1p83) and using Minitest as Testing Engine**

```
class AuthContentType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :auth_permissions
end
```

```
class AuthGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :auth_group_permissions
  has_many :auth_permissions, through: :auth_group_permissions
end
```

```
class AuthGroupPermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :auth_group
  belongs_to :auth_permission
end
```

```
class AuthPermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :auth_content_type
  has_many :auth_user_permissions
  has_many :users, through: :auth_user_permissions
  has_many :auth_group_permissions
  has_many :auth_groups, through: :auth_group_permissions
end
```

When I run > rails test test\controllers\XXXX_controller.rb -n test_should_get_home
I get the following Error:

```
Run options: -b -n test_should_get_home --seed 27312                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                             
# Running:                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                             
E                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                             
Error:                                                                                                                                                                                       
GdControllerTest#test_should_get_home:                                                                                                                                                       
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_content_types_pkey"                                                         
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(980190962) already exists.                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                             
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `exec'                                         
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:92:in `block (2 levels) in execute'                  
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'                                                          
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'                                                
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:91:in `block in execute'                             
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in log'                                   
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'                      
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'                                     
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'                                 
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'                                     
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'                                          
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:721:in `block in log'                                              
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'                                                         
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:712:in `log'                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:90:in `execute'                                      
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:170:in `execute_batch'                               
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:370:in `block (3 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `block in transaction'                          
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_transaction'                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in synchronize'                      
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `handle_interrupt'                                     
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:25:in `block in synchronize'                                 
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `handle_interrupt'                                     
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/load_interlock_aware_monitor.rb:21:in `synchronize'                                          
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transaction'                                
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:280:in `transaction'                                   
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:369:in `block (2 levels) in insert_fixtures_set'       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/referential_integrity.rb:19:in `disable_referential_integrity'              
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:368:in `block in insert_fixtures_set'                  
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:480:in `with_multi_statements'                         
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:367:in `insert_fixtures_set'                           
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:608:in `block in insert'                                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:599:in `each'                                                                                  
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:599:in `insert'                                                                                
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:585:in `read_and_insert'                                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:545:in `create_fixtures'                                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:205:in `load_fixtures'                                                                    
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:118:in `setup_fixtures'                                                                   
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/test_fixtures.rb:8:in `before_setup'                                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.2/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:40:in `before_setup'                                                       
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.3.2/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:322:in `before_setup'                                                               
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activejob-6.0.3.2/lib/active_job/test_helper.rb:45:in `before_setup'                                                                              
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.2/lib/rails/test_help.rb:48:in `before_setup'                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                             
rails test test/controllers/gd_controller_test.rb:4                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                             
.                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                             
Finished in 2.872201s, 0.6963 runs/s, 0.3482 assertions/s.                                                                                                                                   
2 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**Could I be helped on this?** Having been trying to perform some solutions suggested. But it doesn't help me.

Solution:1 (Ran this in the console)

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
    end
```

My test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

end
```

My test\controllers\converge_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ConvergeControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    #get converge_home_url
    get home_url
    #assert_response :success
    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_url
  end

end
```

My test\controllers\gd_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class GdControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get home" do
    get gd_home_url
    #assert_response :success
    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_url
  end

end
```

[image]

Comment: The error shows that you are violating the primary key constraint on the table auth_content_types while loading test fixtures from. Fixtures are using stable ids by building a checksum from the fixture label. Either you are somehow loading fixtures multiple times or the cleanup doesn't work. Please post the content of your `lib/test_helper.rb` and `test/controllers/gd_controller_test.rb`, they are required to find the exact source of the error.

Comment: I have added 'test_helper.rb' and test/controllers/gd_controller_test.rb scripts here

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that my machine has Windows OS, I solved the problem by doing the following:

I commented out the line

```
parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)
```

from my test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  # parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors, with: :threads)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

end
```

[image]

Comment: Parallel testing should be supported on Windows and since Rails should create a different test database for each worker there shouldn't be any conflicts. Maybe this is a bug with parallel testing, that only happens on windows. You could try reporting the problem in the rails issue tracker: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues

Comment: Dude, you're a life saver! I've been stuck with this issue the whole afternoon. I thought I was getting crazy that my tests were written wrong. Doing this solved my issue. I'm using Windows too (not WSL).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have unique index in your database. You add a task and run

> rake database:correction_seq_id
>
> rails g task database correction_seq_id

and then a file generated like lib/tasks/database.rake

you shoul put this block:

```
namespace :database do
    desc "Correction of sequences id"
    task correction_seq_id: :environment do
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |t|
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(t)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @Gizemsoylutr The backtrace shows that the problem happens while loading test fixtures, which have stable (fixed) ids. After loading the fixtures rails already resets the PK sequence to avoid conflicts: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.3.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L610

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
RuntimeError: Wrapped undumpable exception for: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: 
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

Look at the last bit of the error message, for me it says that 'email' needs to be unique (in the users table), but your message might be different.

Go into the offending fixture file, for me (users fixtures), I go into test/fixtures/users.yml but yours might be different.

Remove or comment out anything that creates duplicates that would be violating your db constraint.

If figured it out from info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39578685/5783745)